# Flask Limiter Wait

Tags: python, flask

I want to make an app with flask where you go to a page and if you visit it over 3 times in less than 20 seconds then with flask-limiter you wait some time. But I don't want to wait 20 seconds but 1 minute. Is there any way to do this?
Here is a the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(app,key_func=get_remote_address,default_limits=[])
@app.route('/')
@limiter.limit('3 per 20 seconds')
def home():
    return 'This is home page'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want him if he visited the page over 3 times in less than 20 seconds wait one minute and so on. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps not a solution for those exact timings, but may be worth checking the [rate limiting strategies](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/strategies.html) which you can change, to see if any of these fit your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the decorator as this:

```
@limiter.limit('3 per minute')
```